# RegEx to find value in JSON

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a RegEx on a JSON to match everything that starts with **{$** and ends with **}**

I tried with `/{(.*?)}/g` and it seemingly works fine but if you see the image below it also matches the other text so how do I explicitly write a RegEx for my requirement

The reason for the ask is I need to find values with **{$*}** and replace them with a string

[image]

Below is my JSON

```
{
    "name": "{$StubName}",
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/marks/{$Name}",
        "bodyPatterns": [
            {
                "equalToJson": "{\n    \"name\": \"{$RequestName}\",\n    \"job\": \"{$Role}\"\n}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": "201",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{\n    \"name\": \"{$RequestName}\",\n    \"job\": \"{$Role}\",\n    \"id\": \"{$id}\",\n    \"createdAt\": \"{$Time}\"\n}"
    }
}
```

Comment: in which language are you manipulating the json ? Very likely the easiest way is to parse the json and use the existing api to traverse it.

Comment: JAVA it is @Veverke

Comment: you can prepend "**Don't use**" to your question title. There are many json parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\{\$\w*\}`

[Regex demo](http://regexr.com/55uv7)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: You are right. `\d` is included in `\w` (alphanumeric), and `|` within a character class corresponds to the character `|` itself, not to the OR operator. About `{$}` being a match, I am assuming this is what the OP wants. Thank you for the corrections, fixed.